What's the difference between SMART "long" and "offline" tests?
What's the difference between the two below? What exactly is tested by each test?
smartctl -t offline /dev/sda
smartctl -t long /dev/sda

According to the smartctl documentation:

offline  -  [ATA]  runs  SMART Immediate Offline Test.  This immediately starts the test described above.  This command can be given during  normal  system  operation. The  effects  of  this test are visible only in that it updates the SMART Attribute values, and if errors are found they will appear in the SMART  error  log,  visible with the '-l error' option.
offline - [SCSI] runs the default self test in foreground.  No entry is  placed  in the self test log.
long - [ATA]  runs  SMART  Extended Self Test (tens of minutes to several hours). This is a longer and more thorough version of the Short Self Test described  above. Note  that  this command can be given during normal system operation (unless run in captive mode - see the '-C' option below).
long - [SCSI] runs the "Background long" self-test.

However, this description is somewhat vague and I still don't fully understand the actual difference.
Also, which of the tests performs a complete surface scan and sector reallocation if needed?

die.net is a bit dead. The man page you're referring to is literally 12 years old – A LOT has happened in storage systems and smartctl's abilities in 12 years (from nvme support to fixes to better documentation). You can never be sure if a man page that old still applies to your version of software; don't do that to yourself; more modern man page hosters do exist.


However, this description is somewhat vague and I still don't fully understand the actual difference.

That's because the software can't know the difference. These tests are implemented by the firmware of the drive itself, and they might do exactly the same thing, or wildly different things. This is not about Linux/Unix, this is just SMART, a hardware behavioural standard. And, the offline test is obsolete, so disk vendors don't even have to implement it any more and chances are, for some disks, the two test types are literally the same.

Note that this isn't intended; the name "offline testing" is a terrible misnomer, it should be "do what you need in the background to update some (unspecified) diagnostic parameters that you don't update during normal operation"; it's just that the short or long tests definitely also update the same things. In my experience, these offline tests make absolutely no difference – the things they refresh on my spinning disks are exactly the same that get updated after each power cycle (and I'm not in the business of machines with spinning disks designed to be run 24/7)

As per the man page of smartctl, for short - [ATA], This is a test in a different category than the immediate or automatic offline tests. The "Self" tests check the electrical and mechanical performance as well as the read performance of the disk.  Their results are reported in the Self Test Error Log, readable with the '-l selftest' option.

But really, SMART is merely partially defined in the ATA/ACS standards. While there might be convention(s), even ACS-3 (PDF) itself states that The SMART EXECUTE OFF-LINE IMMEDIATE command causes the device to initiate the set of activities that collect SMART data in an off-line mode...or process a vendor specific self-diagnostic test routine.... If you are interested, you can take a look at it. You'll eventually realize that it really just provide a vaguely defined "interface".

I wonder if with at least some drives, for a complete surface scan and sector reallocation, you really/merely need to rely on "normal read". (The problem is these days even some HDDs are "logically provisioned", meaning that never-written / TRIM'd blocks might not be mapped to any physical sectors, and the LBA-sector mappings might be "highly dynamic" anyway...) (Yes I'm talking about HDDs, not SSDs or SSHDs.)

@MarcusMüller Thank you, I updated the link and quote, although the docs haven't changed much.

@TomYan A very interesting point about "logical provisioning". Still, it depends on what do you pursue with the test. Checking that the surface is still usable to achieve the theoretic capacity or just to verify readability of the already written data.

Well guys, to summarize your comments:
(1) "offline test" is obsolete. (reference please?)
(2) What each test does is unfortunately not well defined by the SMART standard.

https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/test_offline
